# Constant power drain, even with all the fuses pulled

Tags: electrical, jeep, grand-cherokee, battery-drain

The battery is going dead on my 2012 Jeep Grand Cherokee. I'm trying to find the problem with my multimeter. So far I have:

- Taken off the negative battery terminal and connected my meter between the battery and the ground cable. I found a drain current of 2.5 amp.
- Then I started pulling fuses, one by one, and the current dropped to 1.5 amp when I removed the radio fuse.
- After removing all of the fuses, the current is still 1.5 amp.

I'm stumped. Where do I look next? Are there components that could be draining my battery that don't go through the fuse panel?

Comment: Do you have the optional power inverter? It is a 110v outlet located in the rear of the center console.

Comment: No I don't have outlet power inverter

Comment: Check the draw from the alternator.